# Make compact skip NULL

Tags: php

I am using `compact` to build an associative array from some variables. However `compact` is not skipping `null` value.

```
$foo = 'rawr';
$ya = $foo === 'foo' ? 'ya' : null;

print_r(compact('foo', 'ya')); // outputs Array ( [foo] => rawr [ya] => )
```

I also tried to set $ya to a not set variable, but it gave same, like this:

```
$NOTSET;
$foo = 'rawr';
$ya = $foo === 'foo' ? 'ya' : $NOTSET;

print_r(compact('foo', 'ya')); // outputs Array ( [foo] => rawr [ya] => )
```

Is there anyway to set a variable to a value that will be skipped by compact?

Comment: [`unset`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

Comment: Either `unset()` your value or filter your array afterwards.

Comment: @Siguza I cannot do unsert in a tertiary though no? Like `$ya = $foo === 'foo' ? 'ya' : unset($ya);`

Comment: @Noitidart No, you cannot. Variables in PHP work like key/value pairs. No matter the value, assigning it to the key will always make the key exist. You have to step outside of value assignments in order to remove keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [filter the array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) after compacting it:

```
$foo = 'rawr';
$ya = $foo === 'foo' ? 'ya' : null;

print_r(array_filter(compact('foo', 'ya'))); // outputs Array ( [foo] => rawr )
```

Comment: Thanks ArSen this works and is not really too much more verbose!